# Python - Loop through a 2D List - either append values to the current row or delete it

Tags: python, list, loops

I'm attempting to loop through a 2D list, and dependent on factors, either append to the row or remove the entire row

If `tempX` matches a certain value, `tempX` and `tempY` should be appended to the current row in the list. If `tempX` doesn't match that value, the entire row should be removed from the list.

This is the code so far.

```
aList = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15]]

i = 0

for a, b, c, d, e in aList[:]:

    tempC = c
    tempD = D

    tempX = tempC * 2 # These are just a placeholders for another calculation
    tempY = tempD * 2

    if tempX <= 10:
        aList[i].append(tempX)
        aList[i].append(tempY)
    else:
        del aList[i] 

    i += 1
```

**Expected result:** `aList = [[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 16, 18], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 26, 28]]`

Instead this results in

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

## EDIT

After some research, I've come to this solution.

The key is `bList = aList[::-1]` ; this splices the list into reverse order, eliminating the situation in the previous example where I was effectively trying to take tyres off a car without a jack.

```
aList = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15],[16,17,18,19,20],[21,22,23,24,25],[26,27,28,29,30]]
bList = aList[::-1]

i = 0

for a, b, c, d, e in bList:
    tempC = c
    tempD = d

    tempX = tempC * 2
    tempY = tempD * 2

    if tempX >= 50:
        bList[i].append(tempX)
        bList[i].append(tempY)
    else:
        del bList[i]

    i += 1

print bList
```

Which would be a good solution, apart from the fact that it is skipping every second row. I'm not too sure what is causing it to skip rows.

```
[[26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 56, 58], [21, 22, 23, 24, 25], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
[[26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 56, 58], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
[[26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 56, 58], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
[[26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 56, 58], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

**Expected result:** `bList = [[26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 56, 58]]` All the other rows should be deleted

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what you're trying to do. But you can do this kind of stuff with a simple list comprehension. e.g. `result = [a + [a[2] * 2, a[3] * 2] for a in aList if a[2] * 2 >= 50]
`. Recommend you read http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions and then come back to your problem.

Comment: You read from bList and change bList so if you delete row `i` then row `i+1` become `i` and you can't read it in next loop because in next loop your read `i+1`. Save result to new list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without departing too far from your code...

```
aList = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15],[16,17,18,19,20],[21,22,23,24,25],[26,27,28,29,30]]
bList = []

i = 0

for a, b, c, d, e in aList:
    tempC = c
    tempD = d

    tempX = tempC * 2
    tempY = tempD * 2

    if tempX >= 50:
        bList.append(aList[i]+ [tempX,tempY])
    i += 1

print bList
```

Comment: Good. You can even remove `tempC` and `tempD`.